# Select entities using multiple criteria from many-to-many association entity

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm having trouble selecting entities of type Product where the product has two or more Categories.

I have following tables:

```
product
============
product_id (PK)
name

category
============
category_id (PK)
name
```

and their association:

```
product_category
============
product_id (PFK)
category_id (PFK)
```

Now the issue is, that I'm not able to select product according to multiple category.category_id's using product_category table.

For example: I want to select all products which both category 1, 2, that means that there are two occurrences in table product_category.

To select all products with single category a following select can be used

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
JOIN product_category pc using(product_id)
WHERE category_id = 1;
```

But how can I select where the product has category_id 1 and 2? **The query should return only products where both categories are associated.**

```
WHERE category_id = 1 and category_id = 2;
```

This is obviously impossible match, but how can I workaround this? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join a derived table in which you filter all associations for being of either of the wanted categories. Then group by the product and use a `HAVING` clause, that checks for the distinct count of categories being equal to the number of wanted categories. A product having all wanted categories will satisfy this.

```
SELECT p.*
       FROM product p
            INNER JOIN (SELECT pc.product_id
                               FROM product_category pc
                               WHERE pc.category_id IN (1, 2)
                               GROUP BY pc.product_id
                               HAVING count(DISTINCT pc.category_id) = 2)
                       ON pc.product_id = p.product_id;
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved the issue, but I've used the inner select in WHERE clause like WHERE product_id in (SELECT...).